# Git Bash - "No such file" running a bash script with a fully qualified path from cmd.exe

Tags: bash, git-bash

Git for windows installs bash, and the bash.exe is available from windows command prompt.

Starting a bash script fails:

```
bash.exe D:\path\to\script.sh
/bin/bash: D:\path\to\script.sh: No such file or directory
```

This file however exists:

```
type D:\path\to\script.sh
<<< output >>>
```

Forward slashes don't work either:

```
bash.exe /d/path/to/script.sh
```

and neither does piping it:

```
echo '/d/path/to/script.sh' | bash.exe
```

typing

```
cat /d/path/to/script.sh
```

within bash.exe works, however.

/edit:
capitalisation for the device name does not seem to change anything.
and

```
bash.exe \\d\\path\\to\\script.sh
```

does not work either.

Comment: Just guessing, try `bash.exe d:/path/to/script.sh`

Comment: `/d` is a bash syntactic sugar, windows doesn't know about it

Comment: `bash -c "source /d/path/to/script.sh"` would be worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the bash.exe on command prompt without any arguments.
 
Then do a df -m , this will show you where your drives are mounted on.
Example output for my System:

```
$ df -m
Filesystem           1M-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
C:/Program Files/Git    241166 196593     44574  82% /
O:                      798717 739944     58774  93% /o
U:                      798717 739944     58774  93% /u
Y:                      798717 739944     58774  93% /y
```

As you can see the drive where git is installed is mounted as root, but only the Git-Install-Dir.
This means if on your System Git is installed on d: this could be your Problem.
Maybe it's an option to put your script somewhere in your Git-Install-Dir.

Comment: It is not installed on d, and d: is mounted on /d/. Seems to be alright?